# Using colors from array

Tags: javascript

I have this array : `const colorsarray = ['#F2387C', '#8A26A6', '#06ADBF', '#F2CE16']`

And I have a list of item `with unknown number of item`, what I want to achieve is, I want to use these colors as a background color of item, but I want the colors to stay in order.

#### Example

1. Item 1 => bg:#F2387C
2. Item 2 => bg:#8A26A6
3. Item 3 => bg:#06ADBF
4. Item 4 => bg:#F2CE16
5. Item 5 => bg:#F2387C `Go back to the first color`
6. Item 6 => bg:#8A26A6 `Go back to the second color`
7. ...

All I have right now is this code which chooses a color randomly if it could help :

`var randcolor = colorsarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsarray.length)];`

Thanks for helping.

Comment: what effort have you made? please provide some code not just what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: You can use `%` operator. please post the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty simple, thanks to the `%` operator. Here's an example:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('yourclass');
var colors = ['#F2387C', '#8A26A6', '#06ADBF', '#F2CE16']

for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i % colors.length]
}
```

Hope this helps!